# How to save a list of users into database using SpringBoot and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to save a list of users into database using SpringBoot and Hibernate ORM, but unfortunately I am getting a following error:

`"Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList"`

**UserController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    public void addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> newUsers) {
        userService.saveUser(newUsers);
    }
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(List<User> user) {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }
```

**UserSrvice.java**

```
public interface UserService {

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    User getUserById(long id);

    void saveUser(List<User> user);

    void deleteUser(long id);

    User updateUser(int id, Map<String, String> changedFields, String changedByUsername);

}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
@Override
    public void saveUser(List<User> newUsers) {

        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        currentSession.persist(newUsers);
    }
```

**UserDao.java**

```
public interface UserDao {

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    User getUserById(long id);

    void saveUser(List<User> user);

    void deleteUser(long id);

    User updateUser(int id, Map<String, String> changedFields, String changedByUsername);

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Use saveAll() in CrudRepository. I recommend using Spring Data

Comment: But I am not using it I am trying to make it work this way

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for me, hope that it helps someone with the same problem :)

```
public void saveUser(List<User> newUsers) {
        for(User user : newUsers) {
            entityManager.merge(user);
        }
    }
```